# effect of configuring `ttk.Syle().configure` is lost if window looses focus

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I have this code (more or less minimal working example):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        # Create Treeview
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.parent, column=('A', 'B'), selectmode='none', height=7)
        self.tree.pack(expand=True, fill='both', side='top')
        ttk.Style().configure("Treeview", background="#1C1C1C", fieldbackground="#1C1C1C", foreground="white")

        # Setup column heading
        self.tree.heading('#0', text=' Items', anchor='center')
        self.tree.heading('#1', text=' A', anchor='center')
        self.tree.heading('#2', text=' B', anchor='center')

        # Insert some rows
        self.tree.insert('', 'end', text="First item", value=("A's value", "B's value"))
        self.tree.insert('', 'end', text="Second item", value=("A's value", "B's value"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('900x600+300+300')
    App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Notice I changed background color to something nearly black, and the foreground (font color) to white.
This kind of works, except for a detail, which is, when the resulting window doesn't have focus, the font (foreground) still appears black, and the window is almost unreadable.
Like so:

With focus:

[image]

Without focus:

[image]

This is not good enough for me, because there are times in which one wishes to read from one window while having focus on another one.
But maybe this is as good as it gets, concerning the configuration of this widget.
Or am I missing something?

Comment: On my linux system, your code works just fine. With or wthout focus on it. It may be some mac related tweak, that maybe required in your case. MAYBE

Comment: @RishabhKumar Indeed, my computer is a Mac. But other applications I have (which I didn't develop) don't have this problem.